# Error occured while adding managed appliance. SEMP parsing

Tags: solace

I'm trying to connect to appliance soltr-7.1.1.345-vmr-evaluation (on Virtual BOX 5.0.20). However when I am setting to my user global access level to none [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMsix.png), I am getting SEMP parsing problem.[2]

It is connecting normally if I am setting access to read only or read write [3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SolAdmin cannot manage a router when the user has no permissions at all.
The user has neither global access nor VPN access.

The error message is misleading, and will be fixed in the next version of SolAdmin to be more descriptive of the error.